# Android studio copy database file to internal storage

Tags: android, database, button

Is there anyway to copy `Database` file to internal storage instead of external by pressing a `Button`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

define DB_PATH and DB_NAME before calling this method.

```
/**
     * *******************************************
     * Copies your database from your local
     * assets-folder to the just created empty
     * database in the system folder, from
     * where it can be accessed and handled.
     * This is done by transferring bytestream.
     * *******************************************
     */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

        String DB_NAME = "AnArbitraryName.db";
        String DB_PATH = myContext.getDatabasePath(DB.NAME).getPath();

        // Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);


        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH;

        // Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        // transfer bytes from the input file to the output file
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        // Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
        Static.getSharedPreference(myContext).edit()
                .putInt("DB_VERSION", Utils.Version.GetVersion()).commit();
    }
```

Comment: Define DB_PATH and DB_NAME for source (assets) or for destination (/data/.../) folder ? And in the last line you write a new database version. Where and how I can check the version of database in assets?

Comment: Actually the `Utils.Version.GetVersion()` method returns the app's current version. It's an arbitrary number we give with each and every update. 

This was a model i followed when I versioned the databases same as the app version (THere will onle be new update for db structure in new app update. else only update will be data, not structure)..

You can give any arbitrary number as Version.

Same with DB_NAME. it is an arbitrary name for database.

For DB_PATH, I had updated the anser. Use `context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME);`

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can just save the db object to internal storage by getting a FileOutputStream to internal storage by calling `context.openFileOutput(outputFile, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`.

[More info here.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)